# How to give fix space between items and the same space between item's values when print a receipt

Tags: java, android

I need to take a print of my values by giving the command through my tab,and the format should be like this--

```
Name                     amount             quanity

sdfsadfhdasjfsdfds         34                2   

asd                        22                1
```

but the problem is, if value of `name is small` then `format get dis-balanced`.How to give fix space between item so that format remain same.

my code is--

```
builder.append(Name+"\n"    + "           " +amount     + "              "+ quantity + "\n");
```

Comment: refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `String.format()` method:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s %10s %10s", "foo", "bar", "baz"));
System.out.println(String.format("%s %10s %10s", "foofoo", "barbar", "bazbaz"));
```

prints:

```
foo        bar        baz
foofoo     barbar     bazbaz
```

`%10s` tells `String.format()` to prefix the passed strings with spaces until a width of 10 characters is reached.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more details on format strings.

Comment: its not working for me because when i am doing like this---StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(String.format("%s %21s %21s", "foo", "bar", "baz")+"\n");
   
    builder.append(String.format("%s %21s %21s", "anjubvgdfsgfdg","1","23"));
    
    System.out.println(builder);       format gets distrubed

Comment: Hey its perfectly working when i am doing this on console, but when taking a print receipt space does not match as i am required.

Answer (score 1):

Using the String.format() method along with %s you should be able to loop through all the name items (assuming they should be longer than the prices & quantity) then give an int the value of the longest string.

```
String[] items = {"foo", "bar"} // item names
int spaces; // number of spaces

for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){

      if(spaces < items[i].length){

            spaces = items[i];

      }

}
```